# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "por lo tanto" y "por tanto"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

Según la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/tanto):

**por lo ~.**

1. loc. adv. Por consiguiente, por lo que antes se ha dicho, por el motivo o las razones de que acaba de hablarse. U. t. c. loc. conjunt.

**por tanto.**

1. loc. adv. Por lo que, en atención a lo cual. U. t. c. loc. conjunt.

¿Existe alguna diferencia ente una y otra? ¿Es intercambiable? Aquí en México se utiliza más "por lo tanto" de hecho al estar buscando en la RAE fue como me di cuenta de la existencia de "por tanto".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usted no paga sus deudas, perderá su poder de crédito, **por lo tanto** [1*], le será más difícil conseguir nuevos ingresos de dinero, **por tanto** [2*], es de nuestro interés el recordarle que debe pagar sus deudas.

1* Por consiguiente / de ahí en mas

2* Por lo que / entonces

Tal como lo has indicado en tu pregunta

**por lo ~.**

1. loc. adv. Por consiguiente, por lo que antes se ha dicho, por el
   motivo o las razones de que acaba de hablarse. U. t. c. loc.
   conjunt.

**por tanto.**

1. loc. adv. Por lo que, en atención a lo cual. U. t. c. loc. conjunt.

La diferencia es mínima hoy en día, al menos para ámbitos informales.

Comment: Excelente explicación. Coincido en que en el lenguaje informal se usan casi indistintamente.

Answer (score -1):

No hay grandes diferencias, como bien dice cgc y user983248. Pero si a la forma gramatical o formal existe una diferencia bastante importante y cambia el modo de utilización.

En cuestiones gramaticales, el "lo" es una -reduplicación- del objeto directo perdido que en gran parte de los casos es la causa o consecuencia misma. No nos damos cuenta de la diferencia mientras usemos proposiciones y no oraciones simples.

En general la expresión se utiliza como nexo copulativo entre proposiciones consecutivas, pero el "lo" se ha mantenido como un elemento residual de oraciones más simples como:

> Juan bailó bien, por lo tanto ganó el concurso.

Donde la gramática discute a veces si son dos oraciones proposicionales (para mí no lo son ya que tienen el mismo sujeto). Reemplazando podríamos decir:

> Juan bailó bien, por tanto lo ganó [al concurso]

Ese -lo- es una forma de "el concurso". Nos suena mal decir "al concurso" porque estaríamos repitiendo el OD.

Se entiende mejor con este ejemplo:

> Juan bailó bien, por lo tanto lo ganó (Suena un poco mal porque volvemos a repetir el OD)

En una elipsis común se puede eliminar el OD y decir:

> Juan bailó bien, por tanto ganó.
>
> Juan bailó bien, por tanto ganó el concurso.

Aquí podemos usar o no "el concurso" porque no se encuentra el "lo".

No sé si ha quedado muy claro, pero básicamente, en oraciones simples sí es importante si se encuentra o no se encuentra. Cualquier duda me consultas.

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con el OD, es símplemente una locución adverbial.

Comment: No encuentro la caracteristica adverbial en un nexo.